# Alternative to export variable in non interactive shell

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, non-interactive

I have a requirement wherein a script needs to be executed which requires a few environment variables to be set. Typically the following is required:

1) I login to target node, say T1 using 'user1' and set my environment variable, say TEMPDIR=~/tmp; Do a source ~/.bashrc and logoff.

2) Now I'm required to do a non interactive shell script execution. This is
Login to a admin server and run the command:
ssh user1@T1 "sudo -u user2 /path/filescript"

The file script that I execute requires the TEMPDIR to be set.

The above setup doesn't work, as the bash shell is not sourced during non interactive shell (if my understanding is correct). To overcome this, I have tried the below suggestions available in this site and other, but without any luck:

ssh user1@T1 "source ~/.bashrc; sudo -u user2 /path/filescript"

ssh user1@T1 "sudo -u user2 env -i /path/filescript"

Please help. Thanks.

Note: I'm trying to get this done without any intervention from root (I mean using root to set / unset any variables.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure step 1 is necessary in any way:

```
ssh user1@T1 sudo -u user2 env -i TEMPDIR=/home/user2/tmp /path/filescript"
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this. But this doesn't work. Not sure if this is because the second command is run as sudo and is therefore not aware of what was set?

Comment: Ah, I forget `sudo` is restrictive about the inherited environment for security reasons. Your second attempt was closer.

Comment: Was able to get this working by specifying sudo -E (to preserve the original settings). Thanks.